# Synchronize two databases with phpmyadmin - what is the 'socket' for this operation?

Tags: sockets, phpmyadmin, synchronize

I want to synchronize two databases (one on my localhost and second on my server) using phpmyadmin (on my server) and I must fill in a configuration field which is named "socket".

What is this?

Answer (score 1):

this is for a unix socket on the local machine, default is /tmp/mysql.sock, but you can check it out by issue netstat -a | grep mysql to find out the exact one running on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the socket field blank.

Still in case you would like to determine the correct socket, check your *MySQL* configuration or, using the mysql command–line client, issue the *status* command. Among the resulting information displayed will be the socket used.